# Trigger cloned component when click on original in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

I have a loop on a component which represents a list of graph cards on my real app.

I have copied this component ( and loop it ) as the original

Hello Component

```
export class HelloComponent  {
   message:string;
   printedMessage:string
   @Input() elm:string;
  constructor(private data: DataService, private router : Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.message = this.data.messageSource.value;
    this.data.messageSource.subscribe(message => this.message = message)

  }

  updateService(){
    this.data.changeMessage(this.message);
    this.printedMessage=this.data.messageSource.value
  }

  navigateToSibling(){
    this.router.navigate(['/sibling']);
  }
}

app component

<div *ngFor="let elm of [1,2,3,4]">
<hello [elm]= "elm"></hello>
</div>

<h1>Copy </h1>
<div *ngFor="let elm of [1,2,3,4]">
<hello [elm]= "elm"></hello>
</div>
```

DataService component

```
export class DataService {

  messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>("default message");
  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }

}
```

**Expected behaviour**

What I would is when change the input value on the component 1 for example , only the value on the input of the copied component 1 changes.

**Actual behaviour**

Actually when I change a value inside an input all the other inputs are changings.

Here's a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-data-sharing-example-vrc5jk)

Comment: Because you triggering the changeMessage in the service which is in turn sending the new message to all the clones of your component as each one of them has an active subscription to the message source. So if you change the message from any of the clones it will be changed in all of them as you subcription updates the message..

Comment: On your Code every component shares the same Service so if you change data on one component each of them get the same data (since the share the service).
If you want for each component a own Service you have to define it in the Component: 

    providers: [DataService]
However that doesn't solve your problem.
Best would be if you assign the data each component should get by yourself, by adding some logic. Which references the data on the component (for example with the id)
You can either implement this in your service or in the component homing the other components

Answer (score 0):

Below is a solution that will solve you issue. This may not be a perfect solution but you need something similar.

**hello.html**

```html
<h1>App component {{elm}}</h1>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="message">

<button (click)="updateService()" type="button">Save</button> {{printedMessage}}
```

**Data Service**

```js
import {
  Injectable
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  BehaviorSubject
} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  messageSource = new BehaviorSubject < any > ("default message");
  constructor() {}

  changeMessage(message: string, elem: any) {
    this.messageSource.next({
      message: message,
      elem: elem
    });
  }

}
```

**HelloComponent**

```js
import {
  Component,
  Input
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  DataService
} from "./dataService";
import {
  Router
} from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  templateUrl: './hello.html',
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent {
  message: string;
  printedMessage: string
  @Input() elm: string;
  constructor(private data: DataService, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.message = this.data.messageSource.value;
    this.data.messageSource.subscribe(message => this.message = message.elem === this.elm ? message.message : this.message);

  }

  updateService() {
    debugger
    this.data.changeMessage(this.message, this.elm);
    this.printedMessage = this.data.messageSource.value.message;
  }

  navigateToSibling() {
    this.router.navigate(['/sibling']);
  }
}
```

Have also updated the [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-data-sharing-example-vrc5jk). Hope this helps :)